# How to create a nullable field on a Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

How should I create a nullable field on a Django Model For example I want to create a 'newprice' field that if I don't fill it, it doesn't give me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    newprice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @SvenEberth seems pretty self-explanatory to me.

Comment: @joshlsullivan not really. It doesn't describe why one would need to pass both `blank-True` and `null=True` as arguments. I assume "blank" allows it to accept an empty string while "null" allows None to be passed.